# BigCommerce Stencil Custom Layout

Tags: layout, bigcommerce

I've been following how to add a custom layout template to BigCommerce's stencil based theme. Here are the directions: https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/custom-layout-templates

In the store/merchant backend, the place where you would select a custom template is missing. I contacted customer service and they said there is nothing on their end that has to be made to change the account to a beta status as shown on the above link. Does anyone know how to make the page layout dropdown box reappear?

Answer (score 0):

Currently, custom layout templates are in a closed beta for stencil. They will be made available to everyone on Stencil once we've completed the beta. At that time, you'll see the dropdown box reappear in the same location.